# Shapes of arguments in tensorflow RegisterGradient?

Tags: python, tensorflow, derivative

When composing a tensorflow op, often one wants to [register a gradient for that op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RegisterGradient).  The signature for registering a gradient is:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("FooOp")
def _foo_grad(op, grad):
    return bar
```

Suppose that `op` has only one input and one output.
Let `op.inputs[0].shape = [...,N,M]`
Let `op.outputs[0].shape = [...,K,L]`
What shape will `grad` be?  What shape should `bar` be?  The number of partial derivatives of `FooOp` is one per input per output, so bar would be shaped something like `[...,N,M,K,L]`.  Is this intuition correct?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on axes length.

I can't answer for sure this particular question, but take a look at Numpy Broadcast rules to see if help you: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a question about broadcasting.  Specifically, even if my batch dimensions are empty so that `op.inputs[0].shape = [N,M]` and `op.outputs[0].shape = [K,L]`, it is still unclear as to what shape `grad` and `bar` should be from the documentation.